# Why does this circuit for Heisenberg XXZ model look like this?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

So for the XXZ Heisenberg model taken form https://www.tensorflow.org/quantum/api_docs/python/tfq/datasets/xxz_chain: [image]

why is the X interaction part shown as such (with XX, HI, and CNOT):
[image]

I wrote out the matrix and it doesn't seem to agree with the nearest neighbor XX interaction? Thank you!

Comment: Are you comparing to the Hamiltonian? Because as it says the circuit provided is for something that prepares the ground state which is a totally different operation.

Comment: Yep you are right! Thank you!!